# Data is not loading into Model Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please help to find solution, data is not being loaded into model object.

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult ProductDetails(string ItemId)
{
    return PartialView();
}
 
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string ItemId)
{
    listOfShoppingCartModels = GetDetails(ItemId);
    return PartialView("ProductDetails", listOfShoppingCartModels);
}
```

`ProductDetails` view:

```
<div class="container">
   <h2 class="text-center">Product List</h2>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
    <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 2px solid black">
    <div style="text-align: center; border-bottom: 2px solid maroon">
      <h3>@item.ItemName</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
     <div class="col-md-8">
         <img src="@Url.Content(@item.ImagePath)" width="150px" height="150px" />
     </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: left">
         <b>@item.Description</b>
      </div>
</div>
```

Shopping view model:

```
public class ShoppingViewModel
{
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 12: 
> Line 13:     Product List
> Line 14:     @foreach (var item in Model)
> Line 15:     {
> Line 16:
>
> Source File: C:\Users\Sangamesh.Rawoor\Downloads\WebAppECart-master (2) (1)\WebAppECart-master\WebAppECart-master\WebAppECartDemo\Views\Shopping\ProductDetails.cshtml    Line: 14

Comment: Why is your `Index` method a `HttpPost` method?? The basic `Index` method typically should be a `GET` operation - you just want to get some data and show it on screen - nor reason for a `POST` usually...

Comment: If Index is //HttpPost then the following error is:                                                           
                                                                                                                                Server Error in '/' Application.
The current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'ShoppingController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index() on type WebAppECartDemo.Controllers.ShoppingController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String) on type WebAppECartDemo.Controllers.ShoppingController

Comment: Debug your code and make sure `listOfShoppingCartModels ` is not `null` And check if the model is not `null`  in the view before `foreach`

Comment: What does your `ProductDetails` model reference looks like? The `ImagePath` you are getting does that path valid or exist? Could you please share your folder structure and the details of `GetDetails(ItemId)` method, how you are binding image path is important to have a look.

Comment: listOfShoppingCartModels  is not null, Data is loading in listOfShoppingCartModels but not displaying when continue debug

Comment: @foreach (var item in Model), Getting null at model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crate Index HTTPGET action method in order to load your data.